# Pick the greatest number in a range that is also less than the corresponding number in another range's row

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

I have two sets of data in columns A and B. I would like to pick the maximum value from column A which is also less than the value in the corresponding row in column B. I think I ought to be able to do this with the `MAXIFS` function but all the examples I can find compare against static values. I tried these options

```
=MAXIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, "<")
=MAXIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, A&"<"&B)
```

but neither of them worked as expected. In the first case, it is always 0 suggesting the condition is never met, in the second it gives an error.

I know that I could do this by creating a separate region of cells which first filter out the data that doesn't match the conditional and then simply pick the max from what remains but I'd rather do it in a single cell if possible.

Is there a syntax for this comparison and, if so, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there isn't a way of getting it to work with MAXIFS.

You can write this

```
=maxifs(A:A,A:A,"<"&B:B)
```

and it will accept it, but it just uses the first value in column B and doesn't do a side-by-side comparison.

So you have to do it another way e.g. with a combination of Max and If:

```
=ArrayFormula(max(if(A:A<B:B,A:A)))
```

or you can use max with a filter or query:

```
=max(filter(A:A,A:A<B:B))

=max(query(A:B,"select A where A<B"))
```

Comment: Brilliant! the last answer, max(query()), does exactly what I need and is clear enough that I stand a chance of being able to understand it in 6 months when I need to update the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(LEN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(B:B))))>0,
 IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(B:B)))<MAX($A$1:$A),
 MAX($A$1:$A), LARGE(UNIQUE($A$1:$A), 2)), )), 1, 1)
```

[image: 4]

Comment: It isn't clear to me how that answers the question, can you add some explanation?

Comment: if B1 is >= max(A:A) then C1= 2nd biggest number of max(A:A)